# How to make loop perimeter using Control Bevel operation

Tags: modeling

I have selected a loop area on my object and I'm doing the control bevel operation to divide up the mesh. But its creating a loop which goes within the mesh on its -Z direction making like bevelled edge. What I;m trying to achieve is like the sample C. Is saw a tutorial with a Blender user having Hard OPS add-on, and he got what I have in Sample C, (which I did in photoshop just for the purpose of showing what result I'd like to achieve).

[image]

Comment: Please consider . A loop cut of less z height, followed by a scale of the old vertices excluding z, followed by a scale of the new vertices up to z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [**Face Inset**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html?highlight=inset) tool.

Select the outer faces. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to activate Inset.

Un-check *Boundary*

Set the tool to *Offset Even*

To select the newly created faces use *Select Outer*

Then just adjust the thickness.

[image]

To keep the object flat keep the depth at Zero.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used OPS add-on, but you can do it with some extra steps.

1- get to your example B by using bebbel as you would normally do.

2- place your 3d cursor at the same height of the upper faces, either with left click (if you select with right click) or after selecting one of said faces and using the shift+s -> cursor to selected.

[image]

3- Set your pivot point to cursor with "."

[image]

4- finally scale, constraint to z and press 0, this should flatten your bebbel towards the upper faces.

[image]

there might be faster ways to do it, but I hope this method works for your case.